# Finding an algorithm to factor $n$ given cube root $\mod n$

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, factoring, cryptography

Let $p,q$ be unknown primes and $n=pq$.
Also let:
$p\equiv 4 \mod 9$

$q\equiv 4 \mod 9$

Imagine I have an "oracle" that takes **cube roots** $\mod n$. Find a probabilistic algorithm to factor $n$.

I'm not sure where to start. I know the process for factoring $n$ given a **square root** $\mod n$ involves finding $\gcd{(\text{root y mod n}-y,n)}$.

As an example of an oracle that computes *square roots*, I might give it $50^2$ to hopefully factor $n=103\cdot 107$. It says the square root of $50$ is $\equiv 2625\mod 103\cdot 107$. So then it's computed: $\gcd(2625-50,103*107)=103$ and indeed $103$ divides $n$.

I'm assuming the process for cubes is similar, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?  Strictly speaking, the question is unanswerable without more specific details of exactly what your oracle does.  If $\ p\equiv q\equiv1\pmod{3}\ $ (which is always the case when $\ p\equiv q\equiv4\pmod{9}\ $) then an integer $\ m\ $ will have a cube root mod $\ n\ $ if and only if $\ m^\frac{p-1}{3}\equiv1\pmod{p}\ $ *and* $\ m^\frac{q-1}{3}\equiv1\pmod{q}\ $, in which case $\ m\ $ will have  *nine* distinct cube roots mod $\ n\ .$

Comment: If your oracle returns *all nine* of these, then you can construct a *deterministic* algorithm to factorise $\ n\ ,$ or if it returns a single *randomly chosen* cube root, then you can construct a probabilistic algorithm to factorise $\ n\ .$ It would be possible, however, for any  cube roots the oracle returns to be always incongruent both mod $\ p\ $ and mod $\ q\ $ to any other that it might return. In that case, it wouldn't be of any advantage for factorising $\ n\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera it was a problem from our textbook, I have access to the solution now form the professor